# Error: Cannot resolve type entity i10.BidiModule to symbol while building angular Lib project Angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, angular-library, angular-flex-layout

I am facing Error: **Cannot resolve type entity i10.BidiModule to symbol** while building angular Lib project. There are 2 other lib projects which are building fine. This new lib project works well without flex layout and material. But when I use flex layout or material in this project I got below error. I have search a lot. There is solution like including `"preserveSymlinks": true` in tsconfig.lib.json. Unfortunately its not working for me.
Any help on this will be welcome.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue, check if npm legacy-peer-deps config is set to true.(run this to check the config: npm config ls -l ) If it is true, than run this: npm config set legacy-peer-deps false and remove packaga-lock.json and run npm install

Answer (score 23):

I ran into this very same issue today. I had a library project for Angular 13 and after adding the `@angular/flex-layout` as a dependency, I could no longer build the library with the exact same error as you.

I managed to fix the problem by adding `@angular/cdk` as a dependency to my library. I found this information on the flex layout github page, where they install both of these libraries in the "Getting Started" section.

I did not change any other configuration files.

`npm install @angular/cdk --save`

Comment: Thank u worked for me!  Tho had to install the version of @angular/cdk that coincided with the Angular version I was using

Answer (score 4):

My team ran into this when adding SyncFusion modules to some of our shared projects, which we have structured in a monorepo. After much head scratching and failing with the `@angular/cdk` & `preserveSymlinks` solutions out there, I figured out a tweak to my tsconfig.json that made it work for me:

```
    "paths": {
        "@syncfusion/*": [
            "./node_modules/@syncfusion/*"
        ],
    },
```

For whatever reason, Typescript sometimes gets confused about where to find certain packages in our environment. Our tsconfig `paths` section actually has a grab-bag of items in there to smooth things out. Sigh.

Answer (score 4):

Try "npm ls" it will show conflicting dependencies, resolve those. It worked for me.