# Cannot resolve type entity i1.FontAwesomeModule to symbol

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

when I run `ng build` I get this error

```
Error: Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i1.FontAwesomeModule to symbol
    at node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

[minimal reproduction](https://github.com/eng-dibo/dibo/tree/issue/build)
run `cd ngx-cms && npm run tmp`

Comment: I found a fix for similar symptoms by adding the offending "cannot resolve" package to the `path` list in the tsconfig.json. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73453260/957529  Good luck!