# Error: Cannot resolve type entity i2.IconsModule to symbol

Tags: angular, migration, icons, ivy, angular15

I am migrating to Angular 15 from 14 and I came across the the above error upon building the project. Worst part is I cant find any reference of the `i2.IconsModule` withing the project itself. Can you please assist?

> ./apps/ovn-member-client/src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
> Error: Cannot resolve type entity i2.IconsModule to symbol

> ./apps/ovn-member-client/src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
> Error: Cannot resolve type entity i2.IconsModule to symbol

These are the steps I took:

1. I created a new branch
2. Added the dependencies manually
3. Created a global config file
4. Cleared the node module file and re-ran yarn install
5. Sorted out all possible code issues.
6. Still encountering the 2 "ivy" file issues above.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71675705/13762264) looks like it _could_ be a similar issue to yours