Angular compilation initialization failed
`
X [ERROR] Angular compilation initialization failed. [plugin angular-compiler]
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i1.BidiModule to symbol
at reflectTypeEntityToDeclaration (file:///C:/Users/betty/Desktop/EMTECH/Equifarm/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-XZRJJDCL.js:727:11)
at extraReferenceFromTypeQuery (file:///C:/Users/betty/Desktop/EMTECH/Equifarm/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-JO46TGKL.js:1472:26)
at file:///C:/Users/betty/Desktop/EMTECH/Equifarm/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-JO46TGKL.js:1467:12`
Angular compilation initialization failed

You need to add @angular/cdk to your project as it is suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72141600/24202314
